# Upgrading from 10.11.6 El Capitan to 10.12

Tags: mac, macos, mojave, upgrade

I rarely use by mac. Right now I wanted to install a new program on it but it says it won't run unless the OS is 10.12. I only have 10.11.6 (El Capitan) right now and I can't see any updates for upgrading it to 10.12.

Questions:

1. How can I force upgrade it to 10.12? I can't see any updates for it in the store to upgrade it to 10.12. When I Googled, The only one I can find that has a 10.12 is Mojave.
2. If I upgrade my OS to 10.12 will it erase all my previously installed apps and programs? I don't want to do it all again.

Comment: Depends on the Mac you have. You can only upgrade if it is new enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to upgrade to macOS Sierra - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202) will lead you to the [Mac App Store link for Sierra](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?ls=1&mt=12).

You might want to bookmark this too:

[Download Older Versions of macOS and Mac OS X - krypted](https://krypted.com/mac-os-x/download-older-versions-of-macos-and-mac-os-x/)

Comment: will my currently installed programs and apps be safe if I upgrade? no need to reinstall?

Comment: They should be fine, but having a backup is the only guarantee I would trust. Just in case.